Is it possible to calculate inter-rater reliability for one item rated by multiple raters with weights?
I have a survey with a number of statements that had participants categorizing the statements into one of the 4 options they were provided.
The participants were then asked to rate the confidence of their categorizations on a 5 point Likert scale.
I want to compute the inter-rater reliability for individual statements by assigning weights to their categorizations based on their confidence level.
When I try to compute Krippendorff's alpha in SPSS, I'm getting a Zero or 'nan'.
Considering Krippendorff's alpha is a chance adjusted agreement, I have resorted to using percentage agreement. This somewhat removes the usage of confidence of raters. I considered using weighted Cohen's kappa however, the drawback is that it is only for two raters.
Anyone know how I can obtain the inter-rater reliability for one statement(item) multiple raters with weights.

Weighted kappa weights the distances between the values, not the values. Same as Kripp Alpha.
